# How can I display JMockit Coverage report with decimal percentage?

Tags: java, ant, junit, jmockit

I have generated JMockit coverage report using ant task,  but currently it just saw me round up value of percentage coverage. i have thousands of class, so it take too much time to increase round up percentage of coverage.

I need to see progress of coverage in percentage updated with every test class written. so it need to display decimal point with percentage.

Can you please let me know how can i do it?

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you just run each new/modified test class on its own, and then check its coverage report? The global coverage report and its global percentage is not meant for the day-to-day development activies, where the developer is focused on a small part of the system at any given time.

Comment: Do you want to show in the form of a screen shot what your are talking about for better reach.

Comment: @Rao  i have added image for coverage report. currently it saw me 1%, but it may be actually covered 1.30%. i  need to display decimal point in percentage. is there any way..?